# Annotations to detect method calls with wrong order of String parameters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, code-inspection

We have a big application which uses a lot of `Strings`:

- for serial numbers
- for product names
- for order number
- for customer references
- ... and many more ...

Unfortunately our developers are only human. Sometimes the `String` values get mixed up when calling methods.
For example:

```
// this method
public void addProductToOrder(String order, String productname, String serialnumber);

// should be called like:
addProductToOrder(order, productname, serialnumber);

// but is sometimes mistakenly called as:
addProductToOrder(productname, serialnumber, order);
```

Switching 2 parameters is hard to detect when your method takes about 30 of these parameters. (Yes, it's one of those heavy business applications)

*Sidenote: We wouldn't have this problem if we created our own class `SerialNumber` which just acts as a wrapper around `String`. But that seems so wrong.*

Recently, I started to wonder if there is **a way to detect mix-ups using custom annotations**. After all, there are already annotations like `Nullable`, `NonNull` ...
And this is not very different.

We would like to annotate our source code, for example like this:

```
public void addProductToOrder(@OrderReference String order, @ProductName String productname, @SerialNumber String serialnumber);
```

Next, we would like to find a way to make our IDE detect that 2 parameters were switched here.

```
@OrderReference String order = "ORDER_001";
@SerialNumber String sn = "0001-1213-007";
@ProductName String productname = "beer";
addProductToOrder(productname, serialnumber, order);
// should have been: addProductToOrder(order, productname, serialnumber);
```

We are using IntelliJ IDE. **What is possible without writing IDE plugins ?**

Comment: My suggestion is that the easiest way to improve this might be to make a simple data object that encapsulates these fields, and use that as the parameter instead of the multiple strings

Comment: You'd need to write an annotation processor to have errors arise. Go with what ControlAltDel said, it'll be a lot easier, seeing how devs are not forced to enable annotation processing

Comment: I disagree with your sidenote. An own wrapper class for each type (eg: ``SerialNumber.create("0001-1213-007")``) gives you exactly the type safety you want to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you should go with ControlAltDel's comment as an ultimate solution, Intelij does have an inspection "Suspicious variable/parameter name combination" that might help.  You can enter common parameter names and it will warn you if it thinks the local variables do not match.

[image]
[image: Intellij's inspection]

Comment: Tough decision: I voted this as correct answer because it's something that we can start doing today. It's beautiful in its simplicity. The other answer is technically stronger and more interesting though, but unfortunately requires additional dependencies, which makes it harder to introduce in our development team. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your own solution is a good one:  write annotations in code, and run an annotation processor that warns you about problems at compile time.

One easy way to do this is using the [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org/), which enables you to enhance Java's type system with type qualifiers such as `@OrderReference`, `@SerialNumber`, `@ProductName`, etc.  The Checker Framework already comes with example checkers that ensure proper usage of strings, such as regular expressions, format strings, property file keys, and internationalization.  You can start out with something simpler; in fact, you can create a simple type-checker [without writing any code](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#subtyping-checker) beyond definitions of the type qualifier annotations.

An alternative would be to use regular Java types, as you also mentioned.  When possible, that is also a good solution.  However, there are some reasons that may not be possible or desirable, including:  backward compatibility, broader applicability, richer semantics, new supertypes, more precise checking, run-time efficiency, and code clutter.  For a discussion of these issues, see the item "[Should I use pluggable types or Java subtypes?](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-typequals-vs-subtypes)" in the Checker Framework FAQ.

Another alternative is to pass a single container object to your method, instead of passing 30 parameters.  However, this approach has some of the same issues with backward compatibility, etc.  Furthermore, you would still need to ensure that you put values into the right slots of your container, so pluggable type-checking remains relevant.

Comment: The single container approach is indeed a good one. We started applying this about 2 years ago. But as you wrote, it only solves part of the problem. There still is the packing and a lot of unpacking when parameters get dispatched and seperated to more specific methods. PS: Initially we had the same problem for `Integer`'s but that got solved once Java introduced enum types. :)

Comment: Converting from int to enum types is also desirable when you can do it.  When you can't (usually due to need for backward compatibility, such as with Java Swing or Android libraries), then you are stuck with ints.  The Checker Framework has a [Fake Enumeration Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#fenum-checker) to give you strong type-checking in such circumstances.